# Redux update arbitrary nested tree item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

imagine I have this state

```
const state = [
{text: 'node1'},
{text: 'node2', children: [
    {text: 'subNode1'},
    {text: 'subNode2', children: [
        {text: 'node1'}]
    }]
}]
```

So as a requirement, this tree structure can go nested arbitrarily. I want to be able to address the array item `{text: 'node1'}`; the nested one inside node2->subNode2 such that I can edit it and also find that it is a duplicate (has same text) to the one with index 0 in the state array.

Can you help me with that? I need to have a reducer that can mutate the state to reflect this issue given that the nesting can go arbitrarily deeper.

Many Thanks!
Muchtar

Comment: please provide more details as to what you're trying to achieve exactly, with code or pseudocode examples in how you imagine the relations between parent-child work, etc. otherwise, nobody can help you because it's not clear enough. (images / drawings explaining your intent is also great.)

Comment: @Denialos Thanks! Now I edited it. I hope it is clearer.

Comment: I found this post that elaborates on my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569255/find-and-modify-deeply-nested-object-in-javascript-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux with ImmutableJs and recursion can solve my problem. My state nodes must have unique IDs regardless of their depths. 
Credits go to this nice post

[Immutable.js structure (updating nested map)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34818901/immutable-js-structure-updating-nested-map)

I hope this can help others.